# FlowJS: Extract type from Union

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Is it possible in flowjs to extract type from Union type?

I tried the following example, but no luck.

```
type ExtractType = <T>(T | () => T) => T;
type Config = string | () => string;
type S = $Call<ExtractType, Config>;

const str1: S = 'str'; // Error: requires function
const str2: S = () => 'str'; // Error: requires string
```

[try flow](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAogHsATgQwMbACrmgXigHgwD4AKDKAHyhIEoocioM6GmBuAKFEigGEB7AHYAzAJYBzelADOSUYMlVa9RrMTzxnbtADKUgCS9kAG2P54SNJmwAaPkLHiinDqiGyZSAIwAuKHrwAcjVAzjdBDzUAJj8A6hZGYKRQoA)

Answer (score 0):

I simplified the very first line a bit, and it seems to [do the job](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAogHsATgQwMbACrmgXigHgwD4AKDASihyKgwG4AoUSKAYQHsA7AMwEsBzKlADOSXp0EAfKCUrURYiY2bQAykIAkrZABsd+eEjSZsAGjZc+-IowaouohYgCMALijq8AclGIvje05HXwAmd08ZORofJH8gA):

```
type ExtractType = <T>(T) => T;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to extract a union, but I could not get your exact case working, I think Flow cannot solve for a generic when it is used in multiple parts of a union.

Try [this](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAogHsATgQwMbACrmgXigHgwEYAaKDAJgD4AKYqAH3IoEoocrmBuAKFEigBhAPYA7AGYBLAObsoAZySTRspjTYcFSlX2xQAynIAkg5ABsz+eEjSZsZERJlVePVGMVbERAFwG56uycAETiwsLBvEA) as a workaround:

```
type ExtractType = <T1, T2>(T1 | T2) => T2;
type Config = string | () => string
type S = $Call<ExtractType, Config>;

const str1: S = () => "foo";
```